# How to show existing facebook friends who are already using the app on my website.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

When I visit quora.com, (while im logged into facebook) I see a list of some of my facebook friends being shown there as existing users. How is this done. We are implementing facebook login for our website and wish to show a new user his fb friends who are already using our site. Even the friends names and faces being displayed are custom sized on quora.com.

How is the above functionality implemented(showing existing friends before loggin in with custom sized names and faces)

Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What Quora uses is a social plugin called `Facepile`. You can find information about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile

This is great for pre-login/pre-authentication. If you want to show something similar after the login, you could use a FQL query like this:

```
select uid, name, pic_small from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user="true"
```

This selects all friends of the logged-in user and checks if they are using the same app.